# Android Wear app not installing from the mobile package

Tags: mobile, installation, wear-os

Yes, I have followed all the other instructions and links. My wearable app is definitely being **packaged** with the mobile one, but is not installing.

The debug version of the mobile.apk is 4.9MB and of wear.apk is 1.9MB. When I build signed release versions, the mobile.apk is 5.8MB so I believe the packaging is happening.

When I do an `adb install` of the mobile.apk on the handheld, I get the following errors in the logcat of the handheld (the app package is com.pipperpublishing.refwatch so note the strange `refwatch-1` reference in the second error):

```
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.pipperpublishing.refwatch
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:303)
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at com.samsung.aasaservice.AASAUpdateReceiver.onReceive(AASAUpdateReceiver.java:33)
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2948)
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:172)
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498)
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
01-27 07:49:59.129 8729-8729/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)


01-27 07:50:54.219 771-11243/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/app/com.pipperpublishing.refwatch-1: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
01-27 07:50:54.239 771-11243/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
01-27 07:50:54.239 771-11243/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
01-27 07:50:54.239 771-11243/? W/System.err:     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.getHashValueOfPackage(PackageParser.java:5141)
01-27 07:50:54.239 771-11243/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.saveHash(PackageManagerService.java:18383)
01-27 07:50:54.239 771-11243/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$5200(PackageManagerService.java:329)
01-27 07:50:54.239 771-11243/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$20.run(PackageManagerService.java:18368)
01-27 07:50:54.239 771-11243/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
01-27 07:50:54.239 771-11243/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:446)
01-27 07:50:54.239 771-11243/? W/System.err:    ... 5 more
```

I have tried a factory reset of the watch, resyncing, etc etc. Any ideas?

Here's my mobile `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pipperpublishing.refwatch"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 203
    versionName "0.2.03"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
wearApp project(':wear')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my "wear" `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pipperpublishing.refwatch"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 203
    versionName "0.2.03"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Are you signing your apps by a release key? I don't see that in the gradle file; note that the same ky should be used on both components. In addition, to make sure the app is included, open the resulting phone apk and make sure the wear apk is there. Finally, make sure your watch doesn't have a debug version of your wear app installed; if so, first delete the debug version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after multiple uninstalls and reinstalls, but without changing any code, the install is now working. Sometimes I have to "Resync applications" to see changes on the phone. The whole process seems quite clunky.

Comment: AFAICT the system uses the Wear data layer for syncing wearable APKs, and it's far from bulletproof. In particular, I've had numerous instances where they system is installing an old version of my Wear APK. It can sometimes help to completely clear the data layer; see instructions at http://www.tinmith.net/wayne/blog/2014/08/android-wear-total-reset.htm

Answer (score 2):

Only using the release .apk file will the wear application get automatically installed. It wont work using the debug key.

In case the application is signed with a release key, then check whether the application already exists in the android wear device.